# Updating a global variable from a function

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, scope

There is a global variable called numbers. 
Function one calculates a random number and stores it in mynumber variable.

```
var mynumber;

function one (){
var mynumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}
```

I need to use it in a separate function as belows. But an error says undefined - that means the value from function one is not updated.

```
function two (){
alert(mynumber);
}
```

How to overcome this problem. Is there a way to update the mynumber global variable.

Comment: there are two different variables of mynumber in your code. your global variable outside the function, never gets updated. remove var from mynumber inside your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare a variable with `var` it creates it inside your current scope. If you don't, it'll declare it in the global scope.

```
var mynumber;

function one (){
    mynumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; // affects the global scope
}
```

You can also specify that you want the global scope even if you define a local variable too:

```
function one (){
    var mynumber = 1; // local
    window.mynumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; // affects the global scope
}
```

Knowing that the global scope is `window` you can get pretty tricksy with modifying global variables:

```
function one (){
    var mynumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; // local
    window['mynumber'+mynumber] = mynumber; // sets window.mynumber5 = 5 (or whatever the random ends up as)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have:

```
var mynumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
```

Declares a new local variable and then sets a value.  Drop the var and you will update the original.

```
function one (){
   mynumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}
```