# jquery issue with two variables depending on each other

Tags: jquery, variables

I am trying to get a jquery function with two variables working.
Fairly new to this, so please be patient :)

Variable one is defined from the beginning, it can be changed by clicking a specific button (.btn--effect2 or .btn--effect3).
Variable two inserts html into the DOM, when a button with class .trigger is clicked.

Below is the jquery I have come up with.

What is working so far:
As far as the console.log tells me, variable one gets updated, when .btn--effect2 (or 3) gets clicked.

What is not working
Unfortunately the update seems not to take effect for variable one inside the inserted html (variable two).

An interesting Q&A I found [Updating a global variable from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917425/updating-a-global-variable-from-a-function). I tried modifying my code, because I got the feeling something about the scope is off. But I guess, I did not quite understand what to do, as it did not work as expected.

If there is any completely different solution here I missed, please point it out to me.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

```js
var one = "effect1";

$('.btn--effect2').click(function(){
 window.one = "effect2";
    console.log(one);
});

$('.btn--effect3').click(function(){
 window.one = "effect3";
    console.log(one);
});

var two = "<li><div class='post post--"+one+"'><p>Some text.</p></div></li>"

$('.trigger').click(function(){
  $('.list ul li:eq(0)').before(two);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn--effect1">effect1</button>
<button class="btn--effect2">effect2</button>
<button class="btn--effect3">effect3</button>
<button class="trigger">trigger</button>

<section class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><div class="post post--effect1"><p>Some text.</p></div></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><div class="post post--effect1"><p>Some text.</p></div></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><div class="post post--effect1"><p>Some text.</p></div></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Can include `html` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is : in your code, `two` is defined at start and is never changed!

It's not that dynamic.

```js
var one = "effect1";

$('.btn--effect2').click(function(){
 window.one = "effect2";
    console.log(one);
});

$('.btn--effect3').click(function(){
 window.one = "effect3";
    console.log(one);
});

$('.trigger').click(function(){
  var two = "<li><div class='post post--"+one+"'><p>Some text.</p></div></li>"
  $('.list ul li:eq(0)').before(two);
});
```

This should work.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, works like a charm.
So, if the variable is inside the function it does not get called at the start, but when the function is called? Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Exactly. You should study on JS scope to understand and avoid this kind of problem in the future.

Comment: I definitely will. Thanks again!

Comment: @JulianLengfelder In your question, the `var two=` statement might as well be at the top, directly under `var one="effect1"`. By moving it into the `click()` function, there is an actual event that causes the `two` var to be updated. Otherwise, what exactly is updating it, and when? *Answer: nothng and never.*

Comment: @gibberish yea, I get that now.
Another question, do I have to call my variable inside the first to click functions with `window.one` or would `one` itself be enough?

Comment: You must update the variable any time you want the value of `one` to change. In Shikiryu's answer above, the variable will only be updated when the `trigger` button is clicked. If you want it updated at other times, add it to those `.click()` functions also.

Comment: @gibberish I thing you overthink his problem. I don't think he wants to update HTML by clicking any other button than `.trigger` but just update a variable which will by used afterwards when click `.trigger`. Am I right?

Comment: @JulianLengfelder if your `var one = "effect1";` is written in the global scope (not in a loop or an anonymous function, etc -see scope for help-) then window.one === one. Else, it's not the same variable even if they got the same name.

Comment: @Shikiryu Exactly I only want to update on .trigger click. Thank you both for clarifying all of this.